# Xamarin Value Converters not working in data type MvxColor and MvxVisibility

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am trying to implement a converter for android and iOS using MvxValueConverter. I am able to bind a string value using my converter.But if i try to bind a color(MvxColor) or visibility (MvxVisibility) using the same converter it's not work.

```cs
pulic class TwoWayConverter : MvxValueConverter<string, MvxColor>
{
    protected override MvxColor Covert (string value, Type targetType, object parameter, CaultureInfo culture ) 
    {
        return new MvxColor (255,42,0);
    }
}
```

Binding:

```xml
<TextView local:MvxBind="TextColor color, Converter=TwoWay" />
```

Comment: Would you add some code (Converter and Binding), please?

Comment: Pulic class TwoWayConverter : MvxValueConverter<string, MvxColor>{protected override MvxColor Covert (string value, Type targetType, object parameter, CaultureInfo culture ) {return new MvxColor (255,42,0); } }

Comment: <TextView local:MvxBind="TextColor color,  Converter =TwoWay" />

Comment: Have you installed the Color plugin? `TextColor` is part of this plugin.

Comment: I don't understand about Color plugin. How to install color plugin in my project and what is the use ?

Comment: Yes i installed color plug in using nuget problem is fix thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

The `TextColor` and `BackgroundColor` binding targets are not built into the MvvMCross core libraries. They are part of the Color plugin: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Plugins/blob/master/Color/Readme.md

You can install this plugin with NuGet by searching for *MvvmCross.Plugin.Color* in the NuGet package manager or installing it from the command line via

```
Install-Package MvvmCross.Plugin.Color
```

This plugin also offers converters for converting strings to colors (e.g. `MvxRGBAValueConverter`):

**View**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Colored Text"
        local:MvxBind="TextColor Color, Converter=RGBA"/>

    <EditText
        local:MvxBind="Text Color"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**ViewModel**

```cs
public class FirstViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private string color = "FF00FF";
    public string Color
    {
        get { return color; }
        set { SetProperty(ref color, value); }
    }
}
```

For more see: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Value-Converters#the-mvx-color-valueconverters